# For loop for ManytoMany Field Type

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

How should I create a for loop in my template so that I can show a ManyToMany relationship?

Given that:

in models.py I have

```
class Cycle(models.Model):
    cycle_name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    cycle_description = models.CharField(max_length=250)

    def __str__(self):
         return self.cycle_name + "  --  " + self.cycle_description

class Program(models.Model):
    program_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    program_description = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    cycles = models.ManyToManyField(Cycle)
    is_favourite = models.BooleanField(default="False")

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('programs:program', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})

    def __str__(self):
        return self.program_name
```

in views.py

```
class AllProgramsView (generic.ListView):
     template_name = 'programs/index.html'
     context_object_name = 'programs_list'

     def get_queryset(self):
         return Program.objects.all()

 class ProgramDetailView (generic.DetailView):
     model = Program
     template_name = 'programs/program.html'
```

in urls.py

```
#list of all programs
url(r'^$', views.AllProgramsView.as_view(), name='index'),

#single program page
url(r'^(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.ProgramDetailView.as_view(), name='program'),
```

In the single program page I need to list all the cycles that are contained in that specific program.

I've been trying so many different things but none seems to be right.
Here's my current take for the template, which however does not work:

program.html

```
<div class="bg-white">
  <div class="container text-center text-muted">
    <div class="row">
    {% if cycle %}
          {% for cycle in program.cycles.all() %}
      <div class="col-sm-4 py-4">
       <div class="card">
         <p><h5>{{ cycle.cycle_name }}</h5></p>
         <p class="card-text">{{ cycle.cycle_description }}</p>
         <a href="" class="btn btn-secondary">Modify it</a>
       </div>
     </div>
          {% endfor %}
    {% else %}
      <div class="col-sm-12">
            <p>No cycles found</p>
      </div>
    {% endif %}
  </div>
</div>
```

Can someone help, please? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you get no context because the if statement is wrong. 
Instead of

> ```
> {% if cycle %}
> ```

it should be

> {% if program.cycles %}

Comment: Yes! This made it work! Thank you so much @peterpanx